# how to run rtl_fm from a bash script

Tags: python, script, bash, rtl-sdr

I'd like to know if it's possible to run rtl_fm from a .sh file: I know it's possible, but what I'd like to do is to run it, record for 5 seconds (I can place a sleep here) and stop the process (in the terminal, you need to do Crtl+C to do this). Or maybe there is an option to run it for a specific time?
If it's not possible through a .sh script, maybe I could do it through a Python script, but still I'd need some help on this. Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do, but I'm sure it's possible.

Comment: see the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rtl_fm “$@“ & sleep 5 ; pkill rtl_fm ; do_other_things`. Here “$@“ are the arguments passed to your script, replace it with those.